# Setting the Owning Schema For Oracle Membership Provider

Tags: oracle, membership-provider

My team is using Oracle Membership Provider to help manage users for a .NET 4, MVC3 web application. We've recently discovered that our client insists that the schema owning the objects be different from the schema/user the web app uses to connect to the database. Granting permissions to a second schema is not a problem, but how can we configure the Membership Provider to look in a different schema than the connecting user for its tables, functions, etc.?

Comment: I wouldn't make public synonyms. I'd only make synonyms on the connecting user. The problem with that is there are a lot of objects: tables, packages, functions. I'd really rather avoid that route. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synonyms appear to be the only answer. We are not using all of the Membership Provider's functionality, but the following query seems sufficient to generate the synonyms we need:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR ora_obj_rows IS (SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = '&owner_user' AND OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'ORA_ASPNET%' AND OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'PACKAGE', 'FUNCTION'));
BEGIN
FOR ora_obj IN ora_obj_rows
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SYNONYM "' || '&login_user' || '"."' || ora_obj.OBJECT_NAME || '" FOR "' || '&owner_user' || '"."' || ora_obj.OBJECT_NAME || '"';
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

`&owner_user` and `&login_user` are parameters filled in at execution time. (Since we're using scripts, we `DEFINE` them above.) The user executing this query will need to be able to see the objects in ALL_OBJECTS and have rights to create a SYNONYM on the login user. Additionally, appropriate read and write privileges will need to be granted on these objects.

If someone else has something better, I will gladly mark it as an answer.